# $ \exists f:\mathbb C \setminus D \to \mathbb C$ is bounded one-one holomorphic, how?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

We note that there cannot exist bounded one-one  holomorphic map $f:\mathbb C \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb C.$

Put $D=\{z\in \mathbb C: |z|\leq1\}$ (closed disk).

> **My Question**: How to show there exists $f:\mathbb C \setminus  D \to \mathbb C$
>   which is bounded one-one holomorphic?

(I am guessing Riemann mapping theorem may be useful, but I do not know how (here my domain is not simply connected and RMT is  true for simply connected domain), and I am unable to think any other theorem of complex analysis which guarantees one-one and boundedness)

Note see the related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1370415/does-there-exists-bounded-one-one-holomorphic-map-f-mathbb-c-setminus-0)

Comment: What about $z \mapsto \frac{1}{z}$

Comment: @thanks; I got it;

Comment: @user4422: but what will happen if replace $D$ by closed connected and has more than one element,

Comment: If it has non-empty interior you can use the same argument.

Comment: @user4422; sorry, I could not follow you; would you explain me bit more basically I am asking [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1370415/does-there-exists-bounded-one-one-holomorphic-map-f-mathbb-c-setminus-0) ; thanks

Comment: It's very simple. Take $\phi$ a direct similitude map which send an open ball inside some subset $A$ to $D$. (The existence of such map is trivial). Then, $\frac{1}{\phi}$ is the map you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: No need for fancy theorems when there is a very simple explicit example.

Comment: thanks; Oh, I think,  $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ will work. But what will happen if we replace $D$ by closed connected  which has more than one element. thanks